# UV world coordinate on a face?

Tags: three.js, textures, pixel

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but can't seem to find one.
I want to input a UV coordinate and given a face, check where in 3d worldspace that coordinate exists.

So basically, I'd be able to check where certain pixels are on a face in 3d.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_raycast_texture.html

Comment: I'm not looking to raycast an object. I want to supply a uv coordinate and then receive the 3d position where that is located on the face.

Comment: Right. And the math you need is in the `mesh.raycast()` source code. That should help you get started.

Comment: okay, thanks.. I'll look through it and try to understand how to use the math.